# create position / and add text in circle using D3 using "g" and svg in JavaScript /or Coffee

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, coffeescript

so I am trying to seperate each cicle to look something like this

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

here[image]

but with the text inside , but I couldnt' figure it out how my circle would not spread out as I use this coffescript code below

```
svg_w = 800
svg_h = 400
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", svg_w).attr("weight", svg_h)

list = [1,2,3,4,5]
dataset = (x*10 for x in list)
console.log dataset


nodes = svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodes").selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataset).enter().append("g")
            .attr("transform", (d, i) ->

                  d.x = i * 70 + 50
                  d.y = svg_h / 2

                  "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"

                )

nodes.append("circle").attr("class", "node").attr "r", 20
nodes.append("text").attr("text-anchor", "middle").text (d) ->d.name
```

My result show all my circle to upper left coner

[image]

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: The "weight" attribute should be "height", but apart from that it looks like it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to set properties (`d.x` and `d.y`) on a number instead an object. This doesn't work and your translation is undefined. Use separate variables instead, e.g.

```
 dx = i * 70 + 50
 dy = svg_h / 2
 "translate(" + dx + "," + dy + ")"
```

The text doesn't show up because you're referencing a property `.name` that doesn't exist. Also, black text on a black circle isn't visible. You can fix this easily by giving the text a different color and appending the number as the text:

```
nodes.append("text").attr("text-anchor", "middle").text (d) ->d
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LTNQB/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much , this make sense now. Best Answer I got !! very clear :-) !!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why Text is not show up in the middle of my circle. from this line nodes.append("text").attr("text-anchor", "middle").text (d) ->d.name  thought I already did everything that I supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry, had missed that part -- still jetlagged. Will update the answer.